# How I do alphanumeric in-sequence order using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following JavaScript. The final result is display sequence character. 
But I want to display alphanumeric in-sequence order. How do I do that?

```
var disp = '';
var string = '';
var i;
var chars = "0123456789abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

var ran_unrounded;
var ran_number;
var rnum;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    string += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);

    ran_unrounded = Math.random() * 3;
    ran_number = Math.floor(ran_unrounded);
    //document.write(chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1));
    // alert('rnum', rnum, '--', rnum + 1);

    disp = chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 8);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Please give a couple of clear examples of the desired final output. Also, it wouldn't hurt to give an example or two of what your string might look like after the for loop with the random stuff, so we can see what it is you have before trying to sort. (Also, on each iteration of the loop you assign a value to `ran_number` and `disp` but never use those values - it might help if you remove unused code from your question.)

Comment: chars = "0123456789abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; I want result characters like ' sh52 ar87'... how to do it from chars... If you have any coding for do like this,please mention it...

Comment: Are you saying you want to generate a string that contains two random "words", where each "word" has two random letters followed by two random digits? Or does the order of the letters and digits within each "word" not matter such that `'52sh a8r7'` or `'aagw 2352'` would also be acceptable?

Comment: yes... absolutely correct.. i want randomly change like '52sh a8r7' or 'aagw 2352'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so from the clarification in the comments above the requirement is to generate a string that contains two random "words", where each "word" has four characters selected at random from a predefined set of available characters.

Following is one way to do that:

```
var chars = "0123456789abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
function getWord(numChars) {
    var word = "",
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < numChars; i++)
        word += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length));
    return word;
}
function getWords(numWords, numCharsPerWord) {
    var words = [],
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < numWords; i++)
        words.push(getWord(numCharsPerWord));
    return words.join(" ");
}

console.log( getWords(2, 4) );        // "a8ak 1wp9"
console.log( getWords(3, 4) );        // "7ua1 zh80 yy3r"
console.log( getWords(2, 5) );        // "j5ms2 e4xn8"
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dgnwh/